# Есть файл в котором есть текст, мне нужно найти в этом файле название и вывести цену python

Tags: python

Сразу скажу что это мой первый язык который я изучаю, поэтому возможно вопрос глупый.
Есть файл в котором есть текст, мне нужно найти в этом файле название и вывести цену.
Мне нужно чтобы осталась только первая цена, в таком виде : 0.78

Текст файла:

```
table | wood 13$0.78

table | wood 13 (red)$9.61

table | wood 13 (green)$10.61

cupboard | wood 15 (red)$7.45
```

и тд.. около 3000 названий

То что пробовал я, но выводятся все цены сразу:

```
import re
nnn=("table | red 13") #Название каждый раз меняется
inp = open('A:\Programs\file.txt').readlines()

for i in iter(inp):
 if nnn in i:
  cc=str(i)
  bbb=re.compile(r"(?<=[$])\d+\D\d+")
  g=bbb.findall(cc)
  print (g)
```

Comment: Надо выводить только первую подходящую строку которая соответствует заданому шаблону?

Comment: В тексте файла таких строк около 3000, я не буду знать последовательности. Должно получиться так: У меня есть файл со списком продукции(список генерируется через парсер), значение переменной nnn я получаю с сайта, программа находит совпадения в файле, и выводит цену именно того продукта которое в переменной. Проблема в моем коде лишь в том что у меня отображает цену и table | wood 13 и table | wood 13 (red) и table | wood 13 (green) сразу, мне нужно чтобы если я захотел найти table | wood 13, отобразилось только 0.78, а если хочу найти table | wood 13 (red) то 9.61 и тд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код программы:

```py
def find_costs(data, name):
    for line in data:
        if '|' not in line or '$' not in line:
            continue
        if line.split('$')[0].strip() == name.strip():
            return line.split('$')[1]
    return None # на случай, если искомого названия просто нет

# Важно: обратные слеши в путях нужно ставить по два раза.
inp = open('A:\\Programs\\file.txt').readlines()
nnn = "table | wood 13"

print(find_costs(inp, nnn))
```

Исходные данные в файле, который открывает программа:

```
table | wood 13$0.78

table | wood 13 (red)$9.61
table | wood 13 (green)$10.61



cupboard | wood 15 (red)$7.45
```

Результат работы программы:

```py
0.78
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    while True:
        try:
            lines.remove("\n")
        except:
            break

    l = [i.split("$")[1] for i in lines]

print(l[0])
print(l[1]) # for example
```

Comment: Дело в том что таких разных названий в тексте файла около 3000, и я не буду знать последовательности чтобы использовать print (l[0])